# How to set parameter in interface in retrofit request

Tags: java, android, interface, request, retrofit

There is an interface for retrofit:

```
public interface GetDataService {
    @GET("/news")
    Call<ItemAPI> getAllItems();
}
```

How I can give parameters when I do the request? For example,

```
/news?id=1001
```

I think it must be looking like:

```
@GET("/news?id={id}")
```

But how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@GET("/v1/news_content")
Call<ItemPageAPI> getAllItems(@Query("id") String id);
```

@Query can add your parameters to the URL by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like this:

```
@GET("/news?id={id}")
Call<ItemAPI> getAllItems(@Path("id") String idStr);
```

If the `@Path` annotation is not working then you can pass in the `@Query` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface GetDataService {
   @GET("/news?id={id}")
   Call<ItemAPI> getAllItems(@Query("id") int id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set parameters, headers in this way in the retrofit requests

```
  @Headers("Accept: " + "application/json")
  @GET(Constants.GET_PROPERTIES)
    fun getFilteredProperties(@Query("access_token") access_token: String,
                              @Query("lat") lat: String,
                              @Query("long") long: String,
                              @Query("current_page") current_page: String,
                              @Query("location_name") location_name: String
    ): Call<GetPropertiesPojo>
```